# error[E0597]: does not live long enough - Rust

Tags: rust

Estou começando os meus estudos em Rust e estou tendo dificuldades em um programa simples que quero implementar.

A ideia do programa é adicionar o nome de um funcionário e seu cargo em um HashMap através dos dados digitados pelo usuário.

A sintaxe esperada que o usario digite é: **"add < nome_do_usuário > to < cargo > "**

primeiro passo que dou é criar uma variavel chamada **"map"** que armazena o HashMap

Estou atribuindo a uma variavel **"cmd"** o conteudo digitado pelo usuário.

Verifico se o conteúdo da variavél é **"exit"**, caso sim encerro o loop.

Após a verificação crio um Vec através da string com **"split_whitespace().collect()"**

peço pra imprimir o nome e o cargo que ficam indexados na posição 1 e 3 para confirmar os valores.

E então tento adicionar os valores ao map.

```
use std::io;
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut map: HashMap<&str, &str> = HashMap::new();
    loop {
        let mut cmd = String::new();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut cmd).expect("failed to read line");
        let cmd = cmd.trim().to_string();
        if cmd == "exit" {break};
        let vector: Vec<&str> = cmd.split_whitespace().collect();
        println!("{}, {}", &vector[1], &vector[3]);
        map.insert(vector[1], vector[3]);
    };
}
```

Porem recebo esse erro ao tentar compilar:

```
 Compiling teste v0.1.0 (/home/barbieri97/Documents/projetos/rust/the_rust_programming_language/teste)
error[E0597]: `cmd` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:11:33
   |
11 |         let vector: Vec<&str> = cmd.split_whitespace().collect();
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
12 |         println!("{}, {}", &vector[1], &vector[3]);
13 |         map.insert(vector[1], vector[3]);
   |         -------------------------------- borrow later used here
14 |     };
   |     - `cmd` dropped here while still borrowed

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.
error: could not compile `teste` due to previous error
```

Quando tento compilar o mesmo código sem o loop funciona normalmente:

```
use std::io;
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut map: HashMap<&str, &str> = HashMap::new();
    // loop {
        let mut cmd = String::new();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut cmd).expect("failed to read line");
        let cmd = cmd.trim().to_string();
        // if cmd == "exit" {break};
        let vector: Vec<&str> = cmd.split_whitespace().collect();
        println!("{}, {}", &vector[1], &vector[3]);
        map.insert(vector[1], vector[3]);
    // }
}
```

E se tento compilar removendo o ultimo comando que é adicionar os valores ao map também funciona:

```
use std::io;
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut map: HashMap<&str, &str> = HashMap::new();
    loop {
        let mut cmd = String::new();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut cmd).expect("failed to read line");
        let cmd = cmd.trim().to_string();
        if cmd == "exit" {break};
        let vector: Vec<&str> = cmd.split_whitespace().collect();
        println!("{}, {}", &vector[1], &vector[3]);
        // map.insert(vector[1], vector[3]);
    }
}
```

O que posso fazer para conseguir fazer funcionar com o loop?

Answer (score -1):

A questão aqui é que o seu vetor "vector" é um vetor de referências ("borrow") a uma string que é reinicializada dentro do loop. E vc tenta colocar essas referências numa hashmap que existe fora dele, o que levaria a referências a endereços que foram reinicializados.

Como sugestão, use um hashmap de strings (HashMap<String,String>) e insira strings nele. Assim o seu hashmap será dono ("owner") das strings e não incorrerá nesses conflitos.

Em código:

```
use std::io;
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
let mut map: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap::new();
loop {
    let mut cmd = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut cmd).expect("failed to read line");
    let cmd = cmd.trim().to_string();
    if cmd == "exit" {break};
    let vector: Vec<&str> = cmd.split_whitespace().collect();
    println!("{}, {}", &vector[1], &vector[3]);
    map.insert(vector[1].to_string(), vector[3].to_string());
};
```

}

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

use std::io;
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
let mut map: HashMap<& 'static str, &'static str> = HashMap::new();
loop {
let mut cmd: String = ler_cli_input().unwrap();

```
    if cmd == "exit" {break};
     let vector: Vec<& 'static str> = cmd.split_whitespace().collect();
     

   println!("{}, {}", &vector[1], &vector[3]);
   map.insert(vector[1], vector[3]);
 
};
```

}

fn ler_cli_input() -> Result<String,& 'static str>{
let mut buffer = String::new();

```
match io::stdin().read_line(&mut buffer){
    Ok(_) => Ok(buffer.trim().to_string()),
    Err(_) => Err("Erro ao ler cli"),
}
```

}

Tente add Lifetime  , Pois a cada interação com o loop o strSlice ele é tropado